# C# Iterate through nested properties using IEnumerator

Tags: c#, properties, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have seen examples (and official ones) for IEnumerator on lists and arrays or dicts, but I have a different problem. I have classes with properties, how may I implement the IEnumerable and IEnumerator in that case?

My properties classes are:

```
public class standardMessage
{
    public messageProperties message { get; set; }
    public messageFlag flag { get; set; }
}

public class messageProperties
{
    public string messageSubject { get; set; }
    public string messageBody { get; set; }
}

public class messageFlag
{
    public Boolean flagImportant { get; set; }
    public Boolean flagPersonal { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the Program:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        standardMessage myMessage = new standardMessage();

        myMessage.message = new messageProperties
        {
            messageSubject = "Greetings",
            messageBody = "Happy Weekend"
        };

        myMessage.flag = new messageFlag
        {
            flagImportant = false,
            flagPersonal = true
        };

        //how do I iterate through all properties, without knowing how many are there, instead of writing this worm line of code?
        Console.WriteLine(myMessage.message.messageSubject.ToString() + "\r\n" + myMessage.message.messageBody.ToString() + "\r\n" + myMessage.flag.flagImportant.ToString() + "\r\n" + myMessage.flag.flagPersonal.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably in this case just want to override the `ToString` method of the classes.

Comment: Well, you already have the similar question [C# how to implement IEnumerable for nested classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59392109/c-sharp-how-to-implement-ienumerable-for-nested-classes)

Comment: Using reflection you can get an IEnumerable of all of a classes properties. You can then iterate through the properties to get any properties nested within them the same way like iterating through any other tree structure.

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski Thank you for pointing out the other solution; however, it does not implement IEnumerable (despite the fact that properties were singletons, I was looking for a List solution but anyhow) and more important, when I implemented i found out that it does not return the "child" properties. For example, for our question here, I was hoping not just "see" the "message" and "flag" but also the "messageSubject" and "messageBody" within the "message" - and same for "flagImportant" and "flagPersonal" within "flag" of the standardMessage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a very primitive object to json converter. I wouldn't use this in production and it's about 30% slower than Newtonsoft but it get's the job done.

```
private static string PrintObject(object obj, int depth = 1)
{
    var type = obj.GetType();
    if (type.IsPrimitive || type == typeof(Decimal) || type == typeof(String))
        return "\"" + obj.ToString() + "\"";
    var props = type.GetProperties();
    string ret = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
    {
        var val = props[i].GetValue(obj);
        ret += new string('\t', depth) + "\"" + props[i].Name + "\":" + PrintObject(val, depth + 1);
        if (i != props.Length - 1)
            ret += "," + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    return ("{" + Environment.NewLine + ret + Environment.NewLine + new string('\t', depth - 1) + "}").Replace("\t", "  ");
}
```

Gives the result

```
{
  "message":{
    "messageSubject":"Greetings",
    "messageBody":"Happy Weekend"
  },
  "flag":{
    "flagImportant":"False",
    "flagPersonal":"True"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I put it in Main without the private static and worked as you describe. May I ask - if I may - for a thing? I don't usually know the depth, how could I modify to search up to the last level of nested properties? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Don't put anything for the depth parameter. It will start out at 1 when you call it and recursively increment every time it's called. If you want to print a nested object then just call PrintObject(myMessage.flag);

Comment: If this solved your issue could you mark it as answered? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a production-grade way of printing your objects as a formatted string, you need to go and override `ToString` in all your classes to return whatever format you want.

However, if you just want to print the things on screen for debugging or logging purposes, why not JSON?

```cs
public static string ToJson(object @object) =>
    System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(@object, new JsonSerializerOptions{WriteIndented = true});
```

```cs
Console.WriteLine(ToJson(myMessage));
```

Prints

```
{
  "message": {
    "messageSubject": "Greetings",
    "messageBody": "Happy Weekend"
  },
  "flag": {
    "flagImportant": false,
    "flagPersonal": true
  }
}
```

Quick and dirty, but quick and working.

Comment: Thank you very much, may I ask, I get an error for System.Text.Json (as Json doesnt exist in System.Text) - your advice?

Comment: @Nick System.Text.Json is from .NET Core 3.0, if you're using Framework or an older version of Core, get the [System.Text.Json NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json)

Comment: Thank you, it worked as per your advice. I was just wondering if I can do it without Json (problem installing Nuget in another environment, absolutely nothing wrong with your answer..)

Comment: @Nick You can write a serializer yourself, but that's cumbersome. You're probably better off just overriding `ToString` yourself at that point.